# Correct use of option "-o CustomPrintSize=" in cups

Tags: macos, cups

On MacOS, when printing a pdf file from within an application (like Preview), I can click on `Fiery Features` and then on `Full Properties`  and on the `Media` tab I can click in the `Output Paper size` on `Custom` and adjust `Custom Paper Settings.`

[image]

These settings are reflected in the generated postscript:

```
%%BeginFeature: *CustomPrintSize 599.53 841.89
userdict /XJXEFIsetpageproperties known
{<< /XJXsetPrintSize [ 599.53 841.89 0 0 1 ] >> XJXEFIsetpageproperties} if
%%EndFeature
%%BeginFeature: *EFPrintSize CustomPrintSize
%%EndFeature
```

But when I try to do this with the `lp` in the terminal:

```
lp -d MyPrinter some_file.pdf  -o PageSize=A4 -o EFPrintSize=CustomPrintSize -o CustomPrintSize="600.00x842.00"
```

There is no `%%BeginFeature: *CustomPrintSize` in the generated postscript and the print is not the way I want it to be.

I have tried numerous styles for `-o CustomPrintSize`

```
-o CustomPrintSize=600x842
-o CustomPrintSize="600x842"
-o CustomPrintSize="600 842"
-o CustomPrintSize=[600,842]
-o CustomPrintSize="211.5x297.0mm"
-o CustomPrintSize="Custom.211.5x297.0mm"
-o CustomPaperSize=600x842
```

I really need to print from the terminal, because that is scriptable.

**What is the correct way to add an option to the `lp` command to set the `CustomPrintSize` option**

P.S. In the MacOS Gui printer driver settings, they speak about `Custom Paper Size', but the .ppd file, and the generated Postscript all use the term`CustomPrintSize`, it is a bit confusing but I tried both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With CUPS' `lp` command, the "official" way to use custom page sizes is with this syntax:

`lp printername -o media=Custom.WIDTHxLENGTH   filename   # Set size in PostScript points
 lp printername -o media=Custom.WIDTHxLENGTHin filename   # Set size as inches
 lp printername -o media=Custom.WIDTHxLENGTHcm filename   # Set size as centimeters
 lp printername -o media=Custom.WIDTHxLENGTHmm filename   # Set size as millimeters`

No idea how this will interact with your proprietary Fiery controller/printer, though.